# Convert String variable to long

Tags: c#

While i was writing today i've met a very stupid problem:
On one place i must give a long value like 0x70, 0x3BC0 or something like that.
This values i must take from a text file.
I am using System.IO like this:

```
string[] stringTakenByFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"thePathToFile.txt");
```

From here i can take the value but in string format. I mean the same value like 0x70 but not like a long or int but like a text (string). When i try to parse it or convert it from string to int/long it gives me an exception witch says: Input string was not in a correct format.
If you could help me that would be awesome!
Thanks!
EDIT: I dont wanna "How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?" i need from string to LONG

Comment: And how do you try to convert it?

Comment: string variableWhereIStoreTheStringResult;
long variableWhereIwannaStoreTheResult = Convert.ToInt64(variableWhereIStoreTheStringResult);
long variableWhereIwannaStoreTheResult = int64.Parse(variableWhereIStoreTheStringResult);

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64("Your Hex String", 16);` should be the thing you are looking for. 16 here is the number base.

Comment: try this code

    hexNumber = hexNumber.Replace("x", string.Empty);
    long result = 0;
    long.TryParse(hexNumber, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out result);

Comment: @Std_Net , would you post it like an answer. This works PERFECT!

Answer (score 0):

Update : see @Std_Net answer in post comments for an updated solution

If you want to parse a Long in hexa format you must specify it like this :

```
Long.parseLong(myStringToConvert, 16);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa989422(v=vs.80).aspx) documentation

Comment: What is `Long.parseLong` in C#?

Comment: @bviale, are you sure about the syntax ?

Comment: Ok, you are right but @Std_Net gives the best answer in this case.
Thanks about the help anyways.

Comment: Yes, and my method was not up to date, I found out too late that it was not used in the last framework anymore